# ASP.NET - Password Recovery using SMPT.Gmail.Com

Tags: asp.net, smtp, passwords

I have a login control on my webpage along with a RecoverPassword control.

I have the following code inside of web.config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="MyEmail@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="XXXXXXX" port="587"
         userName="MyEmail@gmail.com" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>   
    </system.net>
```

The error that I keep recieving is:
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 35sm26203922ibs.22

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just verify that your password is correct. Try accessing your gmail from the web browser

Comment: Yeah, I have the correct email and password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLS is connection encryption, like SSL.

In .NET 2.0 - 3.5, the smtp config doens't support enabling SSL, which sucks. You have to turn it on using the [EnableSSL property of SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx)

I think they fixed this in 4.0. I have been using an appsetting to enable or disable SSL for smtp.